# Can I animate the reverse state with css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like to animate an `<a>` tag so when in `:active` state it will move to the right and when going back to regular state it would animate back to the left.

Currently it is animating on click but when I leave the mouse button it jumps back with no animation, how can I reverse the animation?

[Here is a simple example](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/DJrIj), please note that i have to use `position:relative;left:20px` since in the real app this code is inside an absolutely positioned element and for some reason, using margin causing unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `left: 0;` for `a` and use `position: relative;` in `a` rather than `a:active`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWb4X/3/)

CSS

```
a {
   display: block;
   background: red;    
   -webkit-transition: left .2s ease-in,margin .2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: left .2s ease-in,margin .2s ease-in;
   transition: left  .2s ease-in,margin .2s ease-in;
   left: 0;
   position: relative;
}
```

Just a suggestion, moving links on click will annoy the visitors, why not use it on `hover`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWb4X/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If your live code is like the example, you just need to put position:relative; and left: 0px; on the a {} rule too.

What is happening is when you stop hovering/release click, it loses the position: relative, because it isn't on the current class. Without the position rule, the left rule is ignored.